# VB.NET Collision between picture boxes interfering with other collisions

Tags: vb.net, collision-detection, collision

So I am attempting (with my limited knowledge of Visual Basics from school) to make a top down type of game where you control a player and go places and do stuff. I am trying to make it easier to make a barrier for the player.

This is what I have so far:

```
If imageIndex > 0 Or imageIndex < 95 Then
        For Each PictureBox In Me.Controls
            If imageIndex > 0 < 23 Then
                If PictureBox IsNot picZombie AndAlso picZombie.Bounds.IntersectsWith(PictureBox.Bounds) Then
                    picZombie.Left += 3
                End If
            End If
            If imageIndex > 24 < 47 Then
                If PictureBox IsNot picZombie AndAlso picZombie.Bounds.IntersectsWith(PictureBox.Bounds) Then
                    picZombie.Left -= 6
                End If
            End If
            If imageIndex > 48 < 71 Then
                If PictureBox IsNot picZombie AndAlso picZombie.Bounds.IntersectsWith(PictureBox.Bounds) Then
                    picZombie.Top += 3
                    picZombie.Left += 3
                End If
            End If
            If imageIndex > 72 < 95 Then
                If PictureBox IsNot picZombie AndAlso picZombie.Bounds.IntersectsWith(PictureBox.Bounds) Then
                    picZombie.Top -= 6
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End If
```

piczombie is the player

0 - 23 = going left

24 - 47 = going right

48 - 71 = going up

72 - 95 = going down

I have made it so when the players image index is between a certain range it will prevent it from going forward if there is a picture box in front of it. But the problem I have is that the code I have makes it happen with picture boxes, panels, labels and basically anything that has a border. I am trying to use panels as things that the player can seemingly go behind but because of the code it prevents it.

I'm guessing there is probably a way more advanced way to code this and I know many people probably don't want to have to deal with an amateur like me, buuuut if someone could help it would be great. And if I have been too vague I apologise in advance.

Comment: Me.Controls returns all Controls, it's not because you call the variable picturebox that it only returns pictureboxes. You could check if the control you are getting is a PictureBox before continueing to check the other stuff

Comment: Change your if statment. "If imageIndex > 0 < 23 Then" to "If imageIndex > 0 and imageIndex < 23 Then"

Comment: That's not the problem. My problem is the first line of code is returning all controls in my form as @Icepickle stated. But I've got no idea on how to make it so it only returns picture boxes.

Comment: I think in VB.Net you could do it like this: `Me.Controls.OfType(Of PictureBox)` You only have to add `Imports System.Linq` on the top of your form if it's not already there. And I would follow @the_lotus, you should clarify and correct your if's ;)

Comment: Thank you so much @Icepickle! I had tried to do the OfType but I didn't realise that I had to have the other 'Imports System.Linq'. It seems to be working as I intended now. Thank you for helping a rookie like me!